# How to display a 12-bit image in C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, pixelformat

I succeeded in displaying an 8-bit bitmap image in C# by using `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed`.

However, I now have a 12-bit raw data image. How do I display it in C#.

Comment: What kind of 12 bit format. Don't think any Windows file format is 12 bit. A 12 bit TIFF perhaps? Do you have any code to share?

Answer (score -1):

I successed in displaying the received 12-bit pixel values by down scaling them to 8-bit pixel values as followings:
...

```
    // Receive bytes from a Device
        board.ReadBytes((int)0xA0, 1024 * 30, ref data_Array1); 
        //restore the 12-bit pixel values
        for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)  
        {
        // This is a 12-bit pixel value.    
        raw_data1[i] = (ushort)((((int)data_Array1[2 * i+1] << 8) & 0x0F00) | ((int)data_Array1[2 * i ] & 0xFF));                       
        }
        // Convert from a 12-bit array to a 8-bit array.
        raw_data_byte1 = DownScale(raw_data1); 
        //create a new Bitmap
       Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(height, width, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette pal = bmp.Palette;
       //create grayscale palette
       for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
       {
         pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb((int)255, i, i, i);
       }

        //assign to bmp
        bmp.Palette = pal;

        //lock it to get the BitmapData Object
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        //copy the bytes
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(raw_data_byte1, 0, bmData.Scan0, bmData.Stride * bmData.Height);
        //never forget to unlock the bitmap
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);
        //display
        this.pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```